# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[The first full election](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Physical Fitness has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the moderator team is:

[image: Thomas Markov was on Strike]

[image: Sean Duggan]

[image: JohnP]

Thank you so much to the outgoing moderators pro-tempore [C. Lange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/31284/c-lange) and [Alec](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/8828/alec). As the two new mods join JohnP on [the moderator crew](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5998691742646272).